# Whats the best way to track the element occurrence and set a corresponding array in Ruby using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape data from a website that contains both `.value` and `.rating-ineligible` classes mixed up.

I want to keep track of both `.value` and `.rating-ineligible` in a single array, to check whether `.value` is available or not:

```
page.css('td.title .value').text.strip
page.css('.rating-ineligible').text.strip
```

I want an array named `FLAG[]`, with elements set as `"A"` when `.value` is present and `"NA"` if `.rating-ineligible` is present
where the output should look something like:

```
FLAG["A","A","A","NA","A","NA","A","A"]
```

Is there any hack that makes the `FLAG` array work?

---

**Sample Input :**

```
<td class=title>

<span class="rating-rating">
<span class="value">8.7</span>
</span>

<div class="rating-ineligible">
<a href="somelink">NYR</a>
</div>

<span class="rating-rating">
<span class="value">5.2</span>
</span>

<span class="rating-rating">
<span class="value">6.1</span>
</span>

<span class="rating-rating">
<span class="value">7.9</span>
</span>

<div class="rating-ineligible">
<a href="somelink">NYR</a>
</div>

<span class="rating-rating">
<span class="value">-</span>
</span>

<span class="rating-rating">
<span class="value">4.2</span>
</span>

</td>
```

If you see the Above Sample Input, there are three types of values present,

```
One is rating   :   *.*
Second is       :   NYR
Third one is    :   - (Hyphen)
```

I want these to be captured in a single array,

In which the value should be set as **"A"** if a valid rating is present in the format **x.x**

The value should be set as **"NA"** if the value present in the input is **NYR**.

and **"-"** if the Hyphen symbol **-** is present in the input.

**Desired Output :**

Flag ["A","NA","A","A","A","NA","-","A"]

Instead of setting flags i tired it by capturing the values into the below array,

```
r = page.css('td.title span.value').text.strip
noe=["NOE"]
ra=r.scan(/./)
ra.map!{|x| x=='-'?noe:x}.flatten!
rat=ra.join("")
rati=rat.scan(/.../)
```

And the output of the array rati[] looks like below,

rati ["8.7","5.2","6.1","7.9","NOE","4.2"]

But here the problem is,
There are totally 8 Values present in the given input,
out of which 5 values are in the format of x.x
one value is in the format of '-' which is captured as NOE in the array
But i am unable to capture NYR in that array.

Now desired output of the above input should look like this,
rati ["8.7","NYR","5.2","6.1","7.9","NYR","NOE","4.2"]
but I dont know the exact way, how to capture the NYR value into the array.

Can anyone gimme the right code to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output.

Comment: Also, please show some sample code that you've tried writing to show you've made an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(DATA.read)
result = doc.search("//td/*[starts-with(@class, 'rating-')]").map do |node|

  case node.elements.first.text
  when /\d+\.\d+/
    'A'
  when 'NYR'
    'NA'
  when '-'
    '-'
  end

end

pp result # ["A", "NA", "A", "A", "A", "NA", "-", "A"]
```